# PowerShell content replacement and escaping double quotes

Tags: powershell

Need to replace `string name = null` with `string name = "Jane Doe";` trying to use below code - no success.

I do not want to save it in parameters and change because of I have to keep doing multiple times in 3rd party application

```
(Get-Content -Path %testPath%) -replace 'string name = null', 'string name = \`"Jane Doe\`"' |
    Set-Content %testPath%
```

Comment: What error are you encountering. The best I can guess is it is actually putting in the `\ ` and backticks. Also dont use `%testpath%`, the PowerShell variable should be `$testPath`.

Comment: Your problem is likely not the replacement operator, the original string, or the substitute string. Before you attempt to replace values in your environment variable, make sure Get-Content is actually returning something. If you want to use Get-Content, try Get-Content -Path Env:\testPath. We don't use percent signs with variables in PowerShell; that's how we displayed the value in a variable in CMD.

Comment: "No success" is not a valid problem description. Please describe in more detail what you expect the code to do and what it actually does. For one thing, `%testPath%` is not a valid variable in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Your whole approach/(original) script line only makes sense to me
when invoked out of a batch file/other higher level management.

Then escaping on multiple levels is always a difficult thing.

As the script line itself is in double quotes,
the inner double quotes have to be escaped from the executing cmd.exe with a backslash.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\23\SO_57618950.cmd
@Echo off
set "testPath=Q:\Test\2019\08\23\foo.txt"
powershell -NoP -C "(Get-Content -Path '%testPath%') -replace 'string name = null', 'string name = \"Jane Doe\"'|Set-Content -Path '%testPath%"'

type "%testPath%"
```

Sample run:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\08\23\SO_57618950.cmd   
# This is foo.txt
string name = "Jane Doe"

# end of text
```